# How to i display only one chatcard for single room instead of multiple chatcard with same rooms?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

How to i display only one chatcard for single room instead of multiple chatcard with same rooms? i am trying to develop a directs box like ig currently messages are displaying correctly with username and profilepic but I am facing a problem that if a user sends multiple messages to any user then multiple chatcard displaying in UI how can I fix this problem?

The only thing which is common is "RoomId" which is coming from backend how can I display that? i am getting RoomId from backend also I do have senderUsername that I want to display but how can I display each chatcard for one room?

i have added some images please check that [from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2wmp.png) you can see a sender name HelloWorld send 4 messages with 4 different chatcards how can display one chatcard for single room?

the RoomId is a room of the users who are chating

```
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { formHead } from '../../CommonCss/FormCss';
import ChatCard from '../../Cards/ChatCard';
import styles from './styles';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const MainChat = ({ navigation }) => {
    
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('')
    const [chats, setChats] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const userDataString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
                const MyData = await JSON.parse(userDataString);

                const response = await fetch(`http://10.0.2.2:3000/g`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        MyUserId: MyData.user._id
                    })
                });

                const data = await response.json();
                let tempChats = {};
                data.forEach((chat) => {
                    if (!tempChats[chat.username]) {
                        tempChats[chat.username] = {
                            username: chat.username,
                            messages: [chat.lastMessage],
                        };
                    } else {
                        tempChats[chat.username].messages.push(chat.lastMessage);
                    }
                });
                setChats(tempChats);
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('chats', JSON.stringify(tempChats));
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        };
        (async () => {
            const cachedChats = await AsyncStorage.getItem('chats');
            if (cachedChats) {
                setChats(JSON.parse(cachedChats));
            } else {
                fetchData();
            }
        })();
    }, []);

    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={24} color="grey" style={styles.backbtn}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("home")}
            />
            <View style={styles.searchSection}>
                <Text style={formHead}>Your Chats</Text>
                <TextInput placeholder='Search'
                    style={styles.searchbar}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setKeyword(text)}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.ChatSection}>
                {
                    chats
                        ? Object.values(chats)
                            .filter((chat) => {
                                if (keyword === '') {
                                    return chat;
                                } else if (
                                    chat.username.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
                                    || chat.messages.some((message) => message.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()))
                                ) {
                                    return chat;
                                }
                                return false;
                            })
                            .map((chat) => {
                                return <ChatCard key={chat.username} chat={chat} />;
                            })
                        : null
                }
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

export default MainChat
```